# is there any problem for a page in WEB-INF to access image in web pages folder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, front-controller

Hello 
i'm working on a j2ee web app with spring 3.0.5 implementing the front controller pattern, with it's dispatcher servlet without the controller using

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="home"/>
```

with ViewResolver. the pages are in WEB-INF/views and images are in /public/images.
it's seems like images are not showing even with width and height specify.

```
<img src="/public/images/Home.png" width="110px" height="110px" />
```

i'm wondering is there is something i'm ignoring or that i should know and do?
 thanks for reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, you need to tell spring where to server static resources from. Try something like this:

```
  <mvc:resources location="/public/images" mapping="//public/image/**"/>
```

Here's a link to more documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html check section 15.12.4

Comment: it works! thanks. One question though : why a double frontslash instead of a single? but location should be `/public/images/` notice the ending slash